# Just for fun everything about the "befana" in LaTeX

Tags: fun

Considering to end of  the holiday time for Christmas I propose the creation of a **befana** (a good old witch who brings presents to the good children and not coal to the bad children).

[image]

I propose this,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,halloweenmath}

\begin{document}
\[\mathwitch_{6}^{\text{january}}=2021\]
\end{document}
```

And any other ideas are welcome.